# Why don't people use nonlinear activation functions after projecting the query key value in attention?

Tags: neural-networks, attention, transformer

Why don't people use nonlinear activation functions after projecting the query key value in attention?

It seems like doing this would lead to much-needed nonlinearity, otherwise, we're just doing linear transformations.

This observation applies to the transformer, additive attention, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure if I got your question right, for the attention model where exactly would you place the non-linearity? Looking at [Graph Attention Networks](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1710.10903.pdf) by Petar Velickovic, they do apply an activation function in eq. 5.

Comment: Can you provide an example of someone not using nonlinear activations in their attention?

Comment: I think what he means is that the queries, keys and values are computed as linear projections, i.e. the input is simply multiplied by a matrix, `q = x * W_q`, `k = x * W_k` and `v = x * W_v` respectively. We could use a non-linear function on each of them, `q = σ(x * W_q)` etc., but it is redundant because later on we use the softmax function and at the end a MLP which also has non-linearities in it.

Answer (score 4):

> It seems like doing this would lead to much-needed nonlinearity, otherwise, we're just doing linear transformations.

Attention is broadly defined as a following operation ($\text{softmax}$ is sometimes replaced by $\tanh$) :

$$\text{Attention}(Q,K,V) = \text{softmax}\left(\frac{QK^T}{\sqrt{d_k}}\right)V $$

Where $Q$, $K$ and $V$ are matrices that are some functions of the inputs.
There are *three* nonlinear operations there:

1. The inner projection $QK^T$ is nonlinear. We have multiplication of two functions of the inputs. For example, in case of self-attention $Q=X W_Q$ and $K = XW_K$ are two linear transforms of the same $X$, so $QK^T = X \left(W_Q W_K^T\right) X^T$ is a quadratic function of the inputs.
2. The $\text{softmax}(x_i) = e^{x_i} /\sum_n e^{x_n} $ function is obviously nonlinear ($\tanh$ as well)
3. The final $\text{softmax}(\dots) V$ product is also nonlinear for the same reasons as (1)

I would say that it is pretty clear that it is definitely not just a linear transformation - there's quite a lot of nonlinearities in the attention block.

---

> This observation applies to the transformer, additive attention, etc.

Let's see what happens next with the outputs of the attention layers:

**In the [transformer](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03762) model**, outputs of the multi-head-self-attention are fed into a feed-forward network inside each block:

[image: Transformer figure1 cutout]

"Feed-forward" means that the inputs are multiplied by a weight matrix and then a nonlinear activation function is applied.

**The [additive attention](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.0473)** approach, directly applies another $\text{softmax}$ on the outputs of what one would call the attention block:

$$e_{ij} = v_a^T \tanh\left(W_as_{i-1} + U_a h_j\right)$$

$$\alpha_{ij} = \frac{\exp(e_{ij})}{\sum_k \exp(e_{ik})}$$

---

To summarize - I don't think that the premise of the question is correct. Various nonlinearities are present both inside the attention blocks and, typically, are applied after the attention is computed.

Comment: Self attention does not meat that $Q = K = X$. It only means that $Q=XW_Q$ and $K=XW_K$ or in other words that K and Q are obtained from the same X, as opposed to cross-attention where keys and queries come from different sequences.

Comment: @hans I stand corrected, thank you. Edited the answer to reflect that